# PHP function to list folders and file, but detect when is a folder or file

Tags: php

How would I edit the following function below...

To allow for the files only to be linked and the folders to be with h1 tags?

For example what I want as the out put is

```
<h1>folder name</h1>
<a href="#">File.txt</a>
<a href="#">File.txt</a>
<a href="#">File.txt</a>
<h1>folder name</h1>
<a href="#">File.txt</a>
<a href="#">File.txt</a>
<a href="#">File.txt</a>
```

Here is the PHP function from another Stackoverflow answer I found that needs editing.

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}
```

I am unsure how to 'detect' that the $ff variable is a folder or file?

Comment: Generally this is done with is_dir which you have?  I can give you the answer but then you will learn nothing.

Comment: `I am unsure how to 'detect' that the $ff variable is a folder or file?` - isn't that exactly what `is_dir()` does?

Comment: This gets me 'Here is the PHP function from another Stackoverflow answer I found that needs editing.' what have you tried doing to edit it.  I suggest looking up "php is_dir" in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you! Directorys are in `h1` and files in `a` tags:

(I'm checking with the function`is_dir` if it's a directory an if it is i'm outputing the name in `h1` and otherwise in `a` tags)

```
<?php
    function listFolderFiles($dir){
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        echo '<ol>';
            foreach($ffs as $ff){
                if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
                    echo '<li>';

                        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff))
                            echo "<h1>" . $ff . "</h1>";
                        else
                            echo "<a href=\"#\">" . $ff . "</a><br />";

                        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                    echo '</li>';
                }
            }
        echo '</ol>';
    }   


?>
```

If you don't want it in a list use this:

```
<?php
    function listFolderFiles($dir){
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
            foreach($ffs as $ff){
                if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){

                        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff))
                            echo "<h1>" . $ff . "</h1>";
                        else
                            echo "<a href=\"#\">" . $ff . "</a><br />";

                        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                }
            }

    }   

?>
```

Comment: And now the OP has learned nothing.  Besides I prefer $ffs = array_diff( scandir($dir), array('..', '.' )); that's just me

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix added a little explanation to what i modifyed at the code! Is that enought for you?

Comment: sure, doesn't matter to me just I always try to teach instead of show, you know teach a man to fish, opposed to giving him the fish.

Answer (score 1):

Using Spl

```
 $dir = new FilesystemIterator( __DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS );
 foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if( !$fileinfo->isDir()){
        echo '<a href="#">'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'</a>';
    }else{
        echo '<h1>'.$fileinfo->getFilename().'</h1>';
    }
 }
```

Haven't tested it.  But it should do the trick, this is the OOP way to do it.  The benefit is you can bypass all the checks for dots and if you like the "/" instead of the "\" on Windows there's a flag for that.

```
FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS
```

Flags are bitwise so to use more then one you do like this.

```
$dir = new FilesystemIterator( __DIR__, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS |  FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS );
```

Answer (score 0):

In this portion, you need to modify:

```
// If $ff is a directory 
if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) {
        // This is where you echo the folder name
        echo '<h1>'.$ff.'</h1>';
        // This will list what's in the directory
        listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dir = scandir('your path');
    foreach($dir as $d) {
        if(is_file($d)) {
            echo $d . ' is file<br>';
        } else if(is_dir($d)) {
            echo $d . ' is directory<br>';
        }
    }
```

just see php manual.

Comment: This wont work, use is_file('your path/' . $d ) instead

Comment: sure scandir only return the filename, or the basename if you will not the path to the file.